# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects, K.shape problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to train Keras R-FCN for my dataset and I need to save full model cause I can't train model all until it finishes so I need to resume my model when I can resume my training.

but I can't save the full model with modelCheckpoint or model.save if I save weight only the code work fine.

I use TensorFlow-GPU 1.15.0 and Keras 2.2.4

```
File "/content/testing.py", line 130, in <module>
    ses.run(main())
  File "/content/testing.py", line 123, in main
    layers='all')
  File "/content/KerasRFCN/Model/Model.py", line 546, in train
    use_multiprocessing=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 251, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 79, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 446, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1090, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 382, in save_model
    _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 83, in _serialize_model
    model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 931, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 220, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

and here is the problem code:

```
    h, w = K.shape(input_image)[1], K.shape(input_image)[2]
    image_scale = K.cast(K.stack([h, w, h, w], axis=0), tf.float32)
    gt_boxes = KL.Lambda(lambda x: x / image_scale)(input_gt_boxes)
```

before i add this code my model work fine and save full model successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I already fixed my problem I'm gonna share my solution. Just like the title said error `typeError: can't pickle thread rlock object` happens apparently because there are raw tensors wandering inside in my model, in this case inside def build from my custom model.

the solution that I take is to make make a function that contains calculations involve with k.shape and called that function inside the lambda layer. Here's the example solution that I took.

Here's the problem code

```
h, w = K.shape(input_image)[1], K.shape(input_image)[2]
image_scale = K.cast(K.stack([h, w, h, w], axis=0), "float32")
gt_boxes = KL.lambda(lambda x: x/image_scale)(input_gt_boxes)
```

and then I move that code into a function

```
def gtBoxes(input_image, input_gt_boxes):
    h, w = K.shape(input_image)[1], K.shape(input_image)[2]
    image_scale = K.cast(K.stack([h, w, h, w], axis=0), "float32")
    gt_boxes = input_gt_boxes/image_scale
    return gt_boxes
```

after that inside def build in my custom model I called it inside lambda layer

```
gt_boxes = KL.Lambda(lambda x: gtBoxes(*x))([input_image, input_gt_boxes])
```

this solution I get from one of the questions from TensorFlow GitHub issue, but I took a different approach since I'm still getting that error even after using the same approach like a solution from that issue.